# how to let servlet know which link has been accessed

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have a code here that opens a new window when i click the hyperlink.

```
<a href="C:\Users\779106\Desktop\eclipse-new\Trial4\WebContent\jsp\video2.jsp" name="1">Chapter 1</a><br/>
<a href="C:\Users\779106\Desktop\eclipse-new\Trial4\WebContent\jsp\video3.jsp" name="2">Chapter 2</a><br/>
```

How can we return a value to the servlet so that it knows which link has been accessed??

Ive made the pages for the two links i've made here. But i need the servlet to know which page has been accessed. Inside the servlet a function is calling a jexcel app. The return value is different for both pages. That is why i need a UNIQUE return value for each link.

Comment: What are some of your ideas to proceed with this problem?

Comment: I want to get a return value or a link to javascript so that i can assign a parameter which can be accessed in the servlet.

Comment: Try Google Analytics :)

Comment: Map the url to servlet and then the server will automatically forward  your request to corresponding servlet

Comment: Why are you linking the files on your desktops ?

Comment: @Renjith i didnt quite understand. Map which url to the servlet?

Comment: Your links would simply load the page from the hard drive into the browser as plain html/text. It would'nt hit a servlet. But what are you trying to achieve here ?

Comment: Okay. Ive made the pages for the two links i've made here. But i need the servlet to know which page has been accessed. Inside the servlet a function is calling a jexcel app. The return value is different for both pages. That is why i need a UNIQUE return value for each link.

Answer (score 0):

The link visited state is stored in the browser, it is not a really good idea to rely on that! It will be gone after a cache clear for instance. You should maintain a DB of user activity, if you need this info on a user level.